# How to pick file with workbook object VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have code like that:

```
Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Set wsCopy = Workbooks("file1.xlsm").Worksheets("Order")
Set wsDest = Workbooks("orders.xlsm").Worksheets("All Data")
lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0).Row
wsCopy.Range("A1:I9" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)
LastRow = Sheets("All Data").UsedRange.Rows.Count
Sheets("All Data").Range("L" & lDestLastRow).Value = "order made?:"
Sheets("All Data").Range("L" & lDestLastRow + 1).Value = "Yes/No"
Range("L" & lDestLastRow).Font.Bold = True
wsDest.Activate
```

In place where i have Workbooks("file1.xlsm") i want pick file to copy.
It is possible using Workbooks or any other method?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you give a more detailed explanation of what you'd like to accomplish?

Comment: Look at `Application.GetOpenFileName`

Comment: In the place where **file1.xlsm** is currently, I want to be able to select the source file from which to copy the data.

Comment: @TimWilliams i know this function, but i don't know how to use this in that example :(

Comment: Are you asking about picking a file to open, or about picking an already-open file?

Comment: Selecting a file and copying the selected range to a new line in the file "orders.xlsm". Currently it works, but the file1.xlsm file is defined and I want to be able to choose a file

Comment: A simple google search would give you this ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.getopenfilename

Comment: It's don't work in this example... or i can't do it

Comment: You want to copy the file?(from windows folder) or you want to copy the data from the file to another file?

Comment: Copy the data to orders.xlsm file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the GetOpenFilename-method, Workbooks.Open and replacing your string with the variable:

```
Dim selectedFilename As Variant
selectedFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:=”Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*”)

If selectedFilename <> False Then
  Workbooks.Open FileName:=selectedFilename
End If

Set wsCopy = Workbooks(Mid$(selectedFilename, InStrRev(selectedFilename, "\") + 1)).Worksheets("Order")
```

Comment: I've done this before, but I'm getting an error (runtime error 9: script out of range). The code snippet after editing:
`Dim wsCopy As Worksheet

Dim wsDest As Worksheet

Dim lCopyLastRow As Long

Dim lDestLastRow As Long

Dim LastRow As Long

Dim selectedFilename As Variant

selectedFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename

If selectedFilename <> False Then
  
Workbooks.Open Filename:=selectedFilename

End If

Set wsCopy = Workbooks(selectedFilename).Worksheets("Order")

Set wsDest = Workbooks("Reports.xlsm").Worksheets("All Data")`

Comment: @rotare updated my answer, the Workbooks() needs the filename and doesn't accept the full path